# Keep new lines when cleaning text in python

Tags: python, text, praw

I am trying to make a reddit scraper. It works fine however I get issues when there are emojis. To try and fix this I found this function on another question.

```
def cleanText(text):
    valid_symbols = "?=-!@#$%^&*()_/\+;:%£$, "  # Symbols that are allowed
    new_text = ""
    for c in text:       # for each character in the text
        if c.isalnum() or c in valid_symbols:  # check if alphanumeric or a valid symbol
            new_text += c
    return new_text
```

This works well to clean the text so it is read correctly however the issues I'm having is that I am losing the newlines. Is there any way I can tell it that new lines are ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add newline (`\n`) to `valid_symbols` i.e. change

```
valid_symbols = "?=-!@#$%^&*()_/\+;:%£$, "
```

to

```
valid_symbols = "?=-!@#$%^&*()_/\+;:%£$, \n"
```

But beware that [newlines do differ between systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), so it migth be necessary to change that to

```
valid_symbols = "?=-!@#$%^&*()_/\+;:%£$, \r\n"
```

You might also use more general solution - allow whitespaces, which mean changing

```
if c.isalnum() or c in valid_symbols:
```

to

```
if c.isspace() or c.isalnum() or c in valid_symbols:
```

Comment: Yeah adding c.isspace() worked, thank you. I didn't realize it was as simple as that I was just over complicating it. Thanks again